# Repetitive values getting echoed/printed out

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm learning PHP and MySQL, just trying to understand stuff right now.
Tried googling this, couldn't find anything on it, or I was looking in the wrong places.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "fakepassword", "fakedbname");

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM testtable");
$datas = array();

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $datas[] = $row;
    }
}

foreach ($datas[0] as $data) {
    echo $data . "<br>";
    }

?>

<?php mysqli_free_result($result);
?>
```

This is what I see when I refresh the page:

[image]

So, to debug it, I entered:

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($datas);?>
</pre>
```

Then it shows me:

[image]

On PHPMyAdmin, I see this:

[image]

If it helps, I manually queried the data into the table using

```
CREATE TABLE testtable (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
A VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
B VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
C VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL)
```

and,

```
INSERT INTO testtable (A, B, C)
VALUES ('Hi', 'There', 'Mark')
```

What's wrong? Why does it repeat itself?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @tadman OP is using `mysqli()`. Just OP is mixing procedural style with object oriented programming style

Comment: @Akintunde007 Sorry for the mixup, I was using mysql, i changed it over to mysqli when I read his comment. it was initially mysql

Comment: @Mark Good to see the switch. PDO is arguably better if you're retooling, so consider that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reformatted your code - Try this

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "fakepassword", "fakedbname");

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM testtable");
$datas = array();

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $datas[] = $row;
 }
}

foreach ($datas as $data) {
 echo $data[0] . "<br>";
 echo $data[1] . "<br>";
 echo $data[2] . "<br>";
 echo $data[3] . "<br>";
}
?>

<?php mysqli_free_result($result); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
array array_unique ( array $array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING ] )
```

Substitute  $array with your array that you want to clean up and then use array_unique as your new one

Comment: Sorry, I roughly understand it, but where should this go?

Comment: put it in your foreach statement right before the echo and instead of echoing out $array try echoing $array_unique

Answer (score 0):

try code below

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "stack");
$qry="select * from testtable";
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$qry);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo $row[0] . "<br>"; //you can use like echo $row['id']
     echo $row[1] . "<br>"; //you can use like echo $row['A']
     echo $row[2] . "<br>"; //you can use like echo $row['B']
     echo $row[3] . "<br>"; //you can use like echo $row['C']
    }
} 
?>
```